# High CPU load after Razor page render completed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I get a weird behavior of Razor - after rendering a web page of approx 300 DIVs, with some user info in each, rendered in a loop, the CPU continues to run at 100% single-core load for about 30 seconds. No IO ops, no change in memory utilization, just burning CPU cycles.

The page is rendering data from the database, 300 records. It's not the database fault - I checked it by disabling DB access, replacing the records with dummy data and obtained the same behavior. The page is rendered and displayed in the browser, no other requests are active, so the server side code (at least my code) is idle.

UPD: The problem ONLY appears when the site is launched from within Visual Studio. Regardless whether it is hosted in IIS Express or IIS.  Both running .NET 4.5.1, MVC 5.1.2. Opening the same site when devenv is not running makes the issue disappear.

Could anyone advise - whether you have experienced a similar issue and how you coped with it, and, how could I identify the piece of code that's causing the problem?

SOLVED!  It's the Browser Link!
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx
Disabling it solves the issue.

Comment: What process, specifically, is utilizing all the CPU resources. Is it `devenv.exe` (the Visual Studio/IIS Express process)? Just because CPU resources spike, doesn't necessarily even mean it's related. It could be some sort of security software that freaked out or hundreds of other things. If it is actually `devenv.exe`, are you running in Debug? There's a lot of stuff still going on in IIS Express when running in debug even after the page is returned, none of which would actually be an issue with a site in production.

Comment: Also CPU spikes can mask other issues. If your computer is swapping memory from RAM, for example, CPU and HDD will spike, but memory utilization could appear stable. In which case, you may just not be running a machine powerful enough to handle Visual Studio (the Win7 one). Long and short, you still haven't done enough diagnosis of the issue for us to truly help you.

Comment: it's the IIS process, w3wp.exe - I observed the same behavior in IIS express and IIS. The CPU is quad-core 4Ghz, 16 gig, no limits set on ram for this particular app.

Comment: Does this behaviour also manifest itself if you were to use webform-based views?

Comment: No. Not even with all Razor pages: so far only two pages happened to be affected.

Comment: @Andy, this is a good question - you should post your findings as an answer though, otherwise it'll appear as being unresolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually it all came down to VS Browser Link. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx)

Happens to be that smaller web pages work just fine, but larger pages cause a disproportionally higher load on the web-server process, making part of the server do something *after* the page is sent to the browser.

Disabling Browser Link solves the problem.

Comment: Very true when you have larger pages!

Comment: This answer has to be marked as the solution. Saved me from hell.